# スタックオーバーフローにおけるマルチポストの扱い

Tags: 討議, マルチポスト

マルチポストを行っている質問をたまに見かけるのですが、スタックオーバーフローではそういった質問はどう扱えば良いのでしょうか？クローズするべきですか？

一般的にはマナー違反だと思うのですが、ナレッジの蓄積という意味で気にしない？
ヘルプにも記載がないようなので質問しました。

Comment: [Why is cross-posting wrong (on an external site)? - Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141823)

Comment: @h2so5 すみません質問の意図が伝わっていませんでした。マルチポストしたいときにどうするかではなくて、マルチポストの質問はクローズ対象なのかが聞きたいのです。

Comment: 質問する側としては少しでも早く回答を得たいという思いがあると思いますので、マルチポストだけを理由にクローズ対象としてしまうのは少し厳しいかなという気がします。

Comment: 個人的には許容範囲だと思っています。どのサイトであるにせよ、問題が解決できるのであれば、それがスタックオーバーフローであれ何であれ、他のユーザにとって有益な情報になると思います。逆にマルチポストであった場合、それを制限することは難しいと思います。(マナーを知らない人にマナーですよ、というのは、時に多くの労力を使うものですから)

Comment: スタック・オーバーフロー（いわゆる日本語版）がマルチポストの投稿先のひとつにされた場合、どのような問題が起こるのか（起こったのか）、具体的な予測や既知の事例がありますか？

Comment: まとまった投稿： [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418/19110)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

マルチポストに対してのスタックオーバーフローには明確なルールが存在しないよう(かつ今後のルール化もなさそう)ですので、**私が**どうするかを皆さんの意見からまとめておきたいと思います。

**結論：マルチポストだからという理由だけではクローズしないが、すでに解決済みである質問がスタックオーバーフロー上で放置されないように対応する。**

以下はその理由と具体的な対応の詳細です。

1. **マルチポストのメリット**

   - より多くの人に質問を見てもらえる。
   - より早く・正確に問題解決しやすくなる(かもしれない)。
2. **マルチポストの弊害**

   - 複数箇所に投稿したことにより、質問自体がメンテナンスされない場合がある(多い？)。
   - 上記により、解決済みであるにも関わらず質問がそのまま放置されてしまう場合がある。
   - 他所で解決済みだった場合、それ以降の回答(者の労力)がムダになる。
3. **マルチポストを見かけたら**

   - マルチポストであること(とできればそのURL)を記載してもらう。
   - どちらかで解決したらどちらでも解決したことを知らせるようにお願いする。
   - 対応してくれなければ断りを入れて編集を行う。
4. **マルチポストをしたくなったら**
   参考URL：[Why is cross-posting wrong (on an external site)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site)

   - マルチポストであることを記載する。
   - できれば時間を開けて(1週間程度)、あちらのサイト(URL)で質問したが良い回答が得られなかったためこちらでも質問することにした、等の断りを入れる。
   - 解決した場合は速やかに質問した全てのサイトに対して解決したことを通知する。

Answer (score 17):

マルチポストが嫌われるのは、マルチポスト行為そのものよりも、「マルチポストする投稿者は立て逃げする傾向が強い」という認識が回答者側にあるからだと思います。

というのは、ちゃんと回答に対してフィードバックをするつもりがある投稿者は、返信する労力の問題もあって無闇に投稿先を増やそうとしないからです。

マルチポストであることを明記してあり複数の投稿先で対応をおこなう意志がある投稿に関しては、クローズする必要は全くないと思います。

Comment: 確かにマルチポストの何が困るかといえば、解決したのかが分からないことでね。別のサイトで解決したのであればもう一方での(解決時点からの)回答はムダになってしまいますし。ひとまずマルチポストを見つけたらクローズではなく、マルチポストを行っている旨を記載してもらう(あるいはこちらで記載する)、解決した場合はどちらでも解決したことを知らせるお願いをするような対応が良さそうですね。

Comment: 個人的にh2so5の回答は正しいと思います。マルチポストであろうかなかろうかより、「当サイトに質のいい適切な質問ですか？」と聞いた方がいいです。いい質問なら、他サイトにも投稿したら問題はないと思います。質の悪い質問なら、マルチポストではなくても、当サイトではクローズするべきだと思います。

Comment: @jmac もちろん上記にある、複数の投稿先で対応を行う意思がある投稿に関してはその通りだと思うのですが、質の良い質問(質の問題ではクローズできない)だがQAサイトにことごとく貼ってあり、解決済みにしてくれそうにない質問をどうするのかを考える必要がありそうです。

Comment: @kotatsu 他のサイトにも投稿された場合、他サイト版は回答済みなら、その回答をここにも適用できると思います（もちろんコピペは控えたほうがいいが、その情報をここに載せるのは大丈夫だと思います）。他サイトに回答なかったら問題ないでしょうし、他サイトに質問自体が探せなくても問題ないですね。

Answer (score 3):

マルチポストがマナー精神に則っているかどうかはどうでもいいというか、マナーを厳密にルール化することは不可能だと思います。ただクローズすべきだったのではないかという考えを抱いたことが何度かありましたので、そのうちの1例を挙げてみます。

ランサーズにて3/7付けで

- [FC2レンタルサーバーでGITコマンドを使えるようにしたい。](http://www.lancers.jp/work/detail/552462)

投稿が行われ、2件の提案が行われました。その後、

- [Fc2レンタルサーバーでOpenPNE3をインストールする](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/7595/fc2%E3%83%AC%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BF%E3%83%AB%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E3%81%A7openpne3%E3%82%92%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)

がSOにマルチポストされ、解決した結果、ランサーズ側の依頼はキャンセルされました。

このケースのように、「SOは無償で回答してくれる便利屋」としてみなされてしまうのは不本意に思えました。

フリーランサーへの経済的な損害もありますが、質問・回答のレベル感を下げ、ナレッジ蓄積の場としてのSOコミュニティ自体の質の低下へ繋がるのではないかという懸念を感じます。

Comment: これは結構特殊なマルチポストですね･･･しかしこの例でいうと仕事を請け負った人もSO質問する可能性がありますね(これも一つのマルチポスト？)。ここまで考えて思いましたが質問って大局的にはほとんどビジネスと関係しているものですよね。そういう観点ではクローズ対象にはならない気がしました。

Comment: 当サイトがほかのサイトより早く・正しく回答がいただけるならいいことだと思いますが、それはなぜ当サイトの質問の質を低下させますか？

Comment: @jmac 「SOは無償で回答してくれる便利屋」という認識の質問者が増えれば、回答者の意欲は低下し、回答者がこのサイトを利用しなくなるのではないでしょうか。統計がないので仮定になりますが、質問よりも回答の方が多い利用者ほど、他人の質問文の編集などメンテナとしての貢献も多いように感じます。責任感のない質問者が流入し、貢献度の高かった回答者兼編集者がいなくなるのであれば、質問の質の低下のみならず、質問をしても回答の得られないサイトになっていくのではないですか？　回答者は感情も承認欲求もある人間なので、早く正しい回答を提供したことを正当に評価され得る環境でなければ、その行為は継続されないと思います。

Comment: @dokubeko 質問者の認識は質問の質と別なことです。もし「SOは無償で回答してくれる便利屋」と思いながら良い質問を聞くと、クローズされるべきでしょうか？質問者の認識を把握する方法がないため、**質問の質を中心に判断**するべきだと思います。責任感がなくても、良い質問（回答できる質問）なら、別いいと思いますし、どんだけ責任感があっても回答できない質問に努力しても、クローズするべきだと思います。英語ではこの現象は「[Help Vampire Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/)」と呼ばれています。悪い目的で良い質問を聞いたとしても、その質問者のためを回答するより、将来に同じ質問のあるいい人を考えたらどうですか？

Comment: @jmac そのように判断することを心がけたり、行動するのはメンテナ（モデレータ）ですが、そのメンテナ自身がこのサイトからいなくなってしまうのではないかと考えます。合理性への理解で感情的な行動を抑制できるよう、サイトとしての働きかけを増やしたほうがいいかもしれません。