# マルチポストとは何ですか？

Tags: サポート, よくある質問, 質問の仕方, マルチポスト

- マルチポストとは何ですか？
- 質問をマルチポストしたい場合にはどうすればいいですか？
- マルチポストを見つけたらどうすればいいですか？

[←FAQ目次に戻る](/q/1484)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### マルチポストとは

「マルチポスト」とは、

- **同じ内容** の質問を、
- **複数** の質問サイト・掲示板・メーリングリスト等に投稿する

ことです。

サイト間での情報の共有が課題となるので、行なう際は下記のガイドラインに従って下さい。

---

### ガイドライン

#### マルチポストする際には

マルチポストである質問を投稿する際は、**下記を明記**して下さい。

- マルチポストしていること
- 他の投稿先（URL）

後から他のサイトに投稿し、結果としてマルトポストになった際も、同じく明記して下さい。質問は後からでも追記や編集ができます。

#### 他のサイトで情報が得られたら

**他のサイトで回答やヒントなどの情報が得られたら、このサイトでも共有**して下さい。方法は2つ有ります。

- [自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)として回答を書く
- 質問を編集して、情報を追記する

得られた情報の種類に応じた方法で共有して下さい。他サイトの投稿を引用する際は、引用元を適切に記載することも忘れないで下さい。

#### マルチポストを見つけたら

マルチポストであるけれど、それが記載されていない質問に気付くことが有ります。そういった質問には、何もしなくても構いません。あるいは、

- マルチポスト先の共有
- このガイドラインの案内

といった情報をコメントで残すと有意義かも知れません。コメントを残す際は、過去に非友好的と指摘されたような、あまりに端的な表現を避け、十分な情報を含めて下さい。

##### 良いコメントの例1

> ```
> こちらのサイトにも同様の投稿がありました。
> 問題解決の参考になるかもしれません。
> https://example.com
> また、もしこの投稿が[マルチポスト](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418/)であった場合は、
> 質問文へマルチポスト先の URL を追記することで、
> 詳細な回答が得られやすくなります。
> ```
>
> —— [「マルチポストを指摘するときのコメント」の supa さんの回答](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3089/)より

##### 良いコメントの例2

> ```
> [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://example.com/) をされているようですが、
> 予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。
> / 参考: [マルチポストとは何ですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)
> ```
>
> —— [cubick さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/98382/#comment112036_98382)をベースにしたもの

##### トラブルを招くコメントの例

> ```
> マルチポスト: https://example.com
> ```
>
> —— [「マルチポストを指摘するときのコメント」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3087/)より

---

### 関連

- [スタックオーバーフローにおけるマルチポストの扱い](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1766/)
- [質問時に他の質問サービスとのマルチポストを明示する必要はありますか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2246/)
- [マルチポストを指摘するときのコメント](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3087/)
- [Is cross-posting wrong (to an external site)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site) (StackExchangeネットワーク全体の議論)