# マルチポストを指摘するときのコメント

Tags: 討議, コメント, 行動規範, マルチポスト

スタック・オーバーフローの質問では、よく他サイトとの[マルチポスト、クロスポスト](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418/19110)を指摘してくださるコメントを見かけます。このコメントには毎回とても助けられていて、というのも回答者からしてみれば既に解決している質問に答えるのはやや無駄が生まれますし、質問者からしてみればマルチポストの問題点を知るきっかけになるからです。

> マルチポスト https://example.com

上のようなコメントはよく見かけられます。

一方で、このようなコメントに対してモデレーター宛てに「非友好的で不親切」として通報がなされることが時々あります。確かに、そもそもマルチポストのなんたるかを知らない質問者にとってみては、このようなコメントが怖く見える場合もあるでしょう。「自分は何らかの不手際を咎められているのでは？」という気持ちになるかもしれません。この感覚は、上のようなコメントに慣れてしまうと生まれにくいでしょうが、そう感じる方々がいる可能性を否定はできません。

私個人的には、他に寄せられているコメントも見て強く問題があると感じられない限りは、通報があったとしてもモデレーター権限を使ってコメントを削除したり編集したりせずにいました。しかし、通報が何回か寄せられる内に、これは一度コミュニティの皆さんのご意見を伺った方が良いのでは、と思うようになりました。

そこで、質問です：マルチポストに関する上のようなコメントは、スタック・オーバーフローの[行動規範](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct)に沿わないレベルで良くないものでしょうか？　良くないのであれば、どのように書けば良いでしょうか？　スタック・オーバーフローを利用する皆さんの率直なご意見を伺いたいです。最終的に、マルチポストを指摘するコメントのテンプレートができると良いなと思っています。

Comment: `[mcve]`と書いたら /help/mcve にリンクされるのと同じように、マルチポストのヘルプへ自動リンクするような書き方があれば指摘しやすくなるかも？と思いついたのでメモしておきます。

Answer (score 10):

スタック・オーバーフローの行動規範に沿わないとも、コメント機能の不適切な使用法とも思いませんが、不快感を与えないよう改善する余地は残っていると思います。

---

> マルチポストに関する上のようなコメントは、スタック・オーバーフローの行動規範に沿わないレベルで良くないものでしょうか？

ヘルプ センターでは、コメントの使用場面について「関係する情報を投稿に追加する」というものが挙げられています<sup>[[1]](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)</sup>。

> #### どんな時にコメントしたらいいですか?<sup>[[1]](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)</sup>
>
> - 作成者に対して明確化をリクエストする
> - 作成者が投稿を改善するのに役立つ建設的な指摘を残す
> - 関係するがささいまたは一時的な情報を投稿に追加する (関係する質問へのリンク、または質問が更新されたことを作成者に知らせる、など)

マルチポスト先をコメントすることは、「関係する情報を投稿に追加する」ことにあたるため、コメント機能の適切な使用方法になると思います。また、実際にマルチポストの指摘を受ける立場になったことはありませんが、少なくとも私はマルチポストの指摘から敵意や、相手をけなす意図を感じることは出来ません。

---

しかし、これは[スタック・オーバーフローでのマルチポストの扱い](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2419)を知ったうえでの判断です。スタック・オーバーフローでのマルチポストの扱いを把握するには、ヘルプ センターではなくメタを確認する必要があり、ある程度スタック・オーバーフローを使い慣れている必要があります。そのため、**質問者がこのサイトでのマルチポストの扱いをまだ把握していない**可能性があります。

また、一部の Q&A サイトでは、マルチポストが[非推奨](https://teratail.com/help#posted-otherservice)、または[明確に禁止](https://mixi.jp/rules.pl)されていたり、嫌悪されている場合があります。このような他サイトでのマルチポストの扱いから、**マルチポスト自体に悪い印象を持っている**質問者も少なくないと思います。

こういった事情を踏まえると、通報の原因は以下のようなものが考えられます。

- 漠然とした指摘を受け、どのように対応すれば良いのかわからず、「非友好的で不親切」と感じた
- マルチポスト先の投稿が質問者本人のものとは限らないにも関わらず決め付けられることで、「不快」に感じた

上記の問題は、次の項目を意識することで解決出来ると思います。

- コメントが「質問に関する情報の追加」だと伝わるようにコメントを書く
- マルチポストだと断定することは控える

例として、以下のようなものを考えてみました。多少、友好的かつ親切に見えるはず...？

> こちらのサイトにも同様の投稿がありました。問題解決の参考になるかもしれません。 https://example.com また、もしこの投稿が[マルチポスト](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418/)であった場合は、質問文へマルチポスト先の URL を追記することで、詳細な回答が得られやすくなります。

Comment: 随分長い間放置してしまい申し訳ありません。私の中で最後の指摘文がいまいちしっくりこないところがあり、悩んでいました。主に2点悩んでいて、(1) 同じ方の投稿でないかもしれない可能性をそこまで考えるべきか (2) たんに URL を追記することを勧めるだけで良いのか。　その上で、先ほどこういう言い方を思いついたので書いてみます：「[こちらにも] (https://example.com) 同様の質問が投稿されていました。もし質問者さんが投稿されたものであれば、こちらをご一読くださいますでしょうか：[マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418/19110)」

Answer (score 7):

***質問です：マルチポストに関する上のようなコメントは、スタック・オーバーフローの行動規範に沿わないレベルで良くないものでしょうか？***

はい。私はそう感じています。

***良くないのであれば、どのように書けば良いでしょうか？***

少なくとも本サイトにおけるマルチポストの取り扱いを説明し、質問者が自分の質問をどのように改善すれば良いのかを示唆する内容にすべきでしょう。
(追記)
本来マルチポスト禁止でない当サイトで必ずそんなコメントをつける必要はない、と言うのが正直なところです。

現在のように極めて一部の人が、マルチポストであることを指摘するだけで何をどう改善すべきかの内容を全く含まないコメントをつけ続けることは、私には自分の考えを押し付けようとするスパムにしか思えません。

Answer (score 7):

マルチポストを指摘するときのコメント、の前提にあるマルチポストに対するスタック・オーバーフローの見解としては、[この回答](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2419/4236)ということでしょうか？ 例えば、マルチポスト投稿者は「より具体的には次のようなことをするべきでしょう。」以下に挙げられている項目を実施すべきということでしょうか？ この点がいまいち明確になっていないように感じています。

スタック・オーバーフローにおいてマルチポスト投稿者が行うべき行動をヘルプページにまとめるのはどうでしょうか？ そうなっていればマルチポストを指摘するときに当該ページを挙げ、指摘内容が明確に伝わると思いますし、指摘者もリンクを挙げるだけで済みます。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフロー運営側の見解というよりかは、スタック・オーバーフローのユーザーさんたちのコミュニティによる現状の見解が、そのヘルプにまとめられていることですね :)　確かに、ある程度合意が得られたところでヘルプにも載せるのは有益そうです。