# マルチポストのFAQを改訂したい

Tags: 討議, マルチポスト, よくある質問の管理

2024-02-09 追記: まず一回、改訂しました。手直しなどあれば、よろしくお願いします。

---

「[マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418/)」というFAQ（[よくある質問](/questions/tagged/%e3%82%88%e3%81%8f%e3%81%82%e3%82%8b%e8%b3%aa%e5%95%8f)）を改訂し、より端的かつ、このサイトの運営方針に絞った文面にしたいと考えています。

FAQの編集には特にルールが有りませんが、これは長く存在し、頻繁に参照されるFAQですので、大きく書き換える前にここで意図を説明したいと思います。意見など有ればお寄せ下さい（もちろん、FAQは単なるwiki化された投稿なので、今回の改訂を終えた後も随時、議論や編集が可能です）。

#### 端的に

長い文章は読まれないのが現実です。下記の点が伝われば十分と考えますので、文章量を大幅に減らしたいです。

- マルチポストとは何か
- このサイトのルール（ヘルプに有る内容と、大きな支持を得ていると言える程度に受け入れられている意見）
- マルチポストした質問者が次に行うべきこと
- 既存の議論へのリンク

#### このサイトの運営方針に絞る

マルチポストに否定的な方の存在は事実ですが、このサイトの運営方針とは関係の無いことです。それに関して「こう感じる方もいる」といった説明をするのは省きたいと思います。

過去の議論で支持を得ている意見に、マルチポストの投稿自体を問題視するものは有りません。有るのは、マルチポスト先を明記して欲しいという意見だけです。それすらも[コメントで要求する必要は無いという意見](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3088/3054)が一定の支持を得ている程度ですので、次に行なうべきこととして端的に説明すれば十分でしょう。

別の例で考えますと、「回答したら『お礼』のコメントくらいはして欲しい」という方も存在しますが、このサイトのルールでは、「お礼」はむしろ禁止に近い扱いです。ですから、そういった感情への配慮などをFAQに盛り込むことは有りません。マルチポストも同じように考えたいです。

#### マルチポストの指摘に関する指針

現在、トラブルの原因になりがちなのが、マルチポストであることを指摘するコメントです（モデレーターとしても何回か通報を受けました）。「[マルチポストを指摘するときのコメント](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3087/)」などを参照し、単純に良い例／悪い例をFAQに含めたいと思います（これは独立したページにするべきかも知れません）。

Comment: 「ちっとも回答がつかないので他所で聞いてみようかと」は丸ごと不要だと思います。マルチポストを行うまでの時間経過は、マルチポストされた投稿の是非を決めるうえで重要な要素ではないので、節にせずにどこかで軽く触れる程度で十分だと考えます。 / また「あるサイトで解決したら他のサイトにも報告する」は「追加の情報は各サイトに反映する」で網羅できる項目だと思うので、削ってしまって良いと感じます。

Answer (score 3):

マルチポスト否定派です。どのようなコメントをしたとしても、９割は放置、残り１割も削除する程度で、マルチポストを有効活用する人は1%に満たない印象です。つまり、マルチポストは投稿された時点で既に死んでいます。

---

その上でSOjaではマルチポストを容認する方針に沿ってコメントをすると…

まず、マルチポストする人は自身がマルチポストしていることを認識していません。技術的質問を行うことに対して初心者であり、SOjaへも慣れていません。そのような方にmetaの特定ページを提示してこれがFAQだと説かれても伝わるのか疑問です。
それよりも、 [ヘルプ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help) に記載し、SOjaの公式見解であることを明示すべきかと思います。ヘルプに掲載することは、同時にSOja初心者が質問前に目を通す確率も上がります。

Comment: 現在、ヘルプの管理は混沌としており、タイポの修正にも2ヶ月かかるという状況です。
まずはこの状況を合理化したいと思っています。
その後、日本語版独自の内容の追加を提案するつもりです。