# Stack Overflow は日本語版と英語版どちらの方が回答されやすいですか？

Tags: サポート

英語が苦手なので日本語で回答したいですが、英語の方が回答が来るでしょうか？
実際に質問された方はもちろん、多くの方のご意見をお聞きしたいです。

Comment: 「日本語で回答したい」は「日本語で質問したい」の間違えでしょうか？

Answer (score 7):

#### 英語版の方が有利

- 英語版の方が利用者数・投稿数ともに多いので、目に留めてもらう確率は英語版の方が高いかもしれません。

#### 日本語版の方が有利

- 一方で、回答率 (Answerd) は英語版 (70%) より日本語版 (77%) の方が高いみたいです。

  https://stackexchange.com/sites
- 英語版で質問した場合、内容によっては話題に特化した別の関連サイトを勧められるかもしれません。
- 各サイトごとに「話題の範囲」というルールが微妙に異なりますが、日本語版では「日本語でのやり取り」に主眼を置いているのである程度ゆるいルールです。

---

常にずばりの回答だけがつくとは限らず、コメントで明確化を求められる場合なども考えると「コミュニケーション」に自信のある場所を優先して投稿するのが重要じゃないかと思います。

なお、ルールに沿っていれば両方に投稿することももちろん可能です。
(英語版なら英語で、日本語版なら日本語で投稿など)

Comment: 合わせて読みたい: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418/19110)

Answer (score 5):

英語を母語ないし第二言語とするユーザは、明らかに日本語圏のユーザよりも数多く存在します。

後述する特殊ケースを除くと、英語版 Stack Overflow の方が圧倒的にアクティブユーザ数が多く、有用な回答がつく可能性が高いと思います。

特殊なケース：

- 日本語圏や日本国内でしか利用されないソフトウェア等に関する質問
- 作者が日本語話者であるソフトウェア等に関する質問

Comment: 英語版SOとココ日本語版SOの両方で質問・回答の経験がありますが、当然ながら母語（日本語）の方が気軽に質問・回答を書き込めます。ただまあ、本当に困っているなら英語版SOをお勧めしておきます...

Answer (score 3):

貴方の質問の分野や内容に、関心を持っている/知識・経験がある/調べて回答しても良いと考えている、といった人がどれだけサイトを覗いているか、にかかっていると思われます。

貴方の質問と同分野の質問・回答・承認されたものがどれだけあるか、回答までの期間は？ といったことをタグやキーワードで調べてみるのが良いかもしれません。

まあそれよりも解決したい疑問や課題があるなら、ヘルプの記事を参考にして質問を行ってしまった方が早いでしょう。
[質問にあたって](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
[私たちのモデル](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/stackexchange)

[Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
[Our model](https://stackoverflow.com/help/stackexchange)

Answer (score 2):

日本語版に投稿し、数日待って満足のいく回答が得られなかったら英語版にもマルチポストする、で問題ないと思います。
実際に一度やったことがありますが、とくにそれに対して問題視する反応はありませんでした。